# Zoom Video conference on Pi 3 B+

Tags: video, zoom-meeting

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with the Zoom Video Conference System. But i totally fail. Any thoughts how to accomplice that? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far please, and which step is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it is possible to do everything you need from the browser without any proprietary extensions, I think it will not be possible. You should try with Firefox or Chromium.

Zoom only provides x86 builds of their meeting client application, so you won't be able to run it on Raspberry Pi devices, which are ARM.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. i'll it with the browser!

Comment: How did this go in the end? Was the Pi powerful enough?